# How to implement child protection firewall that cannot be bypassed?

Tags: firewalls

As a guardian, we wish to protect our family especially children from malicious websites.

We implemented the following technologies:

- [K9](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/)
- Symantec client protection

But it can be surpassed with [ultra surf](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ultrasurf-security-privac/mjnbclmflcpookeapghfhapeffmpodij?hl=en)

We're too much worried on this. Can someone kindly advise on implementing a much secure firewall?

Comment: Why are you worried? Why aren't those technologies meeting your needs?

Comment: @schroeder Ultra surf allows to by pass firewalls. We just need to prevent access to malicious websites

Comment: So, you want a firewall that your kids cannot bypass? There are lots of ways to bypass firewalls.

Comment: Typically, parental controls like this are meant to deter the curious, not to control the determined. Large organisations with dedicated security teams struggle to do what you want to do.

Comment: @schroeder Oh, I had asked a [question about you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/262084/349200) last year.

Comment: Only completely reliable method would be a whitelist of allowed websites, dropping all others at router level, and ensuring that no proxy sites are in the whitelist...

Comment: uninstall chrome and use a browser w/o plugins

Comment: @dandavis This is not an option. Is there anything concrete?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into using a DNS service like OpenDNS? OpenDNS has content filtering as part of their services. I'm sure there are other providers but they are the ones I'm familiar with.

Comment: This requires DNS IP configuration right? The DNS IPs can be changed by anyone. Correct me if wrong

Comment: @Student you are correct